# How to start service in dialer (default or stock dialer) of android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-service, android-service-binding

I want start a service when my dialer (default or stock dialer) open. My service just toasts a message. How to start the service for dialer. The `startService` command is working in `MainActivity`, but it is not working while a dialer is open.

My code is shown below:

**Manifest.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.chatheads">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DIAL_ACTION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />


    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" />

    <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.chatheads;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.DialerKeyListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button startService,stopService;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startService=(Button)findViewById(R.id.startService);
    stopService=(Button)findViewById(R.id.stopService);




    if(getIntent().getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_DIAL)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class);
        startService(intent);

    }

    startService.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startService(new Intent(getApplication(), MyService.class));




        }
    });
    stopService.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stopService(new Intent(getApplication(), MyService.class));



        }
    });


  }
}
```

**Myservice.java**

```
package com..service;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    intent.getStringExtra("MY_MESSAGE");
    //stopSelf();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}
```

This code is not working. The service starting when the startService calling in MainActivity. But when a dialer open it not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you can try changing `getApplication ()` to `MainActivity.this`.

And I think you need to jump from the dialer to `MainActivity` to get the service started